# can't send post data to api in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

i can't send post data to api using django rest framework. i used postman to send data only user part is adding to the database , the activity of user is rejecting . i can't figure out problem can anyone help me to solve this problem

**sending post data to api**

```
{
        "name": "karen",
        "username": "karen",
        "timezone": "US/Samoa",
        "activity_periods": [
             {
                "log_in": "2020-06-09T21:53:25.120897Z",
                "log_out": null
            },
            {
                "log_in": "2020-06-09T22:02:35.289891Z",
                "log_out": null
            },
            {
                "log_in": "2020-06-09T22:03:36.425212Z",
                "log_out": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

but only the user data is stored the activity is ignored
like this

```
 {
        "name": "karen",
        "username": "karen",
        "timezone": "US/Samoa",
        "activity_periods": []
    }
```

how can i add activity data to user...?

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TIMEZONES, default='UTC')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="activity_periods",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    log_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    log_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
 class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Activity
            fields = ['log_in', 'log_out']


 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        # Passing login Logout to User
      activity_periods = ActivitySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ['name', 'username','timezone', 'activity_periods']
```

**views.py**

```
class ActivityListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    name = "activity-list"
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('rest/',views.ActivityListView.as_view())
```

how can i add activity data to user...?

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserSerializer`, you have the following line:

```
activity_periods = ActivitySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Since `read_only` is set to True, when you `POST` data it will not be written to the database. Try setting it to False instead.

Comment: After setting read_only=False , It throws Error :                                                  AssertionError at /rest/
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `app1.serializers.UserSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields